# PHP approach to creating article list

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing

I plan to write function to dynamically create article and news list, but don't know exactly what would be proper approach.

I have `/articles` and `/news` folders containing files like `article1.php`, `article2.php` etc.

These files contain variables `$date` (publishing date), `$type` (news/article), `$h1, $h2` (title, subtitle), `$short` (short paraghaph to display on list).

I want to create a list of these files displaying on one page.

HTML:

```
<div>
    $content <!--here goes list of all articles/news-->
</div>
```

Would it be better to:

1.

- Write while loop in `articlelist.php`:

```
[pseudocode]

    $content = "";
    while (get another filename from /articles)
       include filename
       $content .= (variables from filename.php parsed into html)
    display $content
```

- And second the same loop for `newslist.php`.

(With this approach e.g. sorting articles by date could be difficult.)

Or maybe:

2.

- Create `articlearray.php` and `newsarray.php` files storing data from each article and news file in array in form `key : value = $date : [$type, $h1, $h2, $short]`
- Create `parsearray` function parsing whole given array to HTML (containing data from all files)
- Call `$content = parsearray(...)` in `articlelist.php` and `newslist.php`
- Display $content.

Or is there some other better solution?

**EDIT:**

I don't have any database because of really small amount articles/news. I'll use one if it'll be really necessary, but at the moment please assume that it should be done with pure PHP. (I asked this question also for learning purposes, not only practical.)

Comment: Have you considered a database?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if I want to use database only for this purpose. I plan to make a simple page with about maybe 30-40 articles/news. This is the reason I consider not-so-efficient, but just simple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Managing your content and or code in different files is recommended (for better understandability and maintainability), but not obligatory. I would chose the following approach. Separate your content into three files:

1. `index.php` (Contains "main" functions)
2. `data.php` (Contains data)
3. `functions.php` (Contains callable functions)

## index.php

```
// index.php

require_once 'data.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

$allowedModules = array('articles', 'news');

if(empty($_GET['m']) || null === $_GET['m']) {
    die('Module is required');
} else {
    $module = $_GET['m'];
}

if(!in_array($module, $allowedModules)) {
    die('Invalid module');
}

echo execute($module);
```

## data.php

```
// data.php

$data = array(
    'articles' => array(
        array(
            'date' => '2014-06-10',
            'type' => 'article',
            'h1' => 'My Headline #1',
            'h2' => 'Subheadline #1',
            'short' => 'My teaser'
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '2014-06-09',
            'type' => 'article',
            'h1' => 'My Headline #2',
            'h2' => 'Subheadline #2',
            'short' => 'My teaser'
        )
    ),
    'news' => array(
        array(
            'date' => '2014-06-08',
            'type' => 'news',
            'h1' => 'My News Headline #3',
            'h2' => 'Subheadline #3',
            'short' => 'My teaser'
        ),
    )
);
```

## functions.php

```
// functions.php

function execute($module) {
    global $data;
    $content .= '<div>';
    foreach($data[$module] as $item) {
        $content .= '<span>' . $item['date'] . '</span>';
        $content .= '<h1>'. $item['h1'] . '</h1>';
        // $content .= ...
    }
    $content .= "</div>";
    return $content;
}
```

Now you can call your page via `index.php?m=articles` or `index.php?m=news` to show your articles or news.

Sidenote: This approach makes it somehow easy to switch to a database later.

Comment: Thank you. Since no one suggested a better solution for my situation, I should probably accept your answer as it seems to be really the best approach (and I'll use it in future projects, if I'll still won't be using SQL to store this kind of data).